# Slider hiding menu items

Tags: jquery, css

I am developing a website in asp.net, I have used jquery image slider and jquery menu.
It is working fine for my website but when go to menu and populate sub items in menu it doesn't display properly. Image slider hide the menu item. I search a lot but didn't find any solution.
Please help me out.[image]

Comment: if you use a higher `z-index` for example, `100` might get it on top. Can you give a link to your page so I could provide you with an exact solution?

Comment: Currently i did not host my website anywhere. Is there any other property in css for stay on top other then z-index

Comment: no, but keep in mind, `z-index` only works on fixed positions `position: relative` / `position:absolute` / `position:fixed` assigned for that element. if it doesnt work try it wil `z-index:9999` which is the highest

Comment: blackpla9ue, you should probably submit this as an answer instead of a comment, so that this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your menu element with the following CSS:

```
z-index:1
```

Or ensure your image element has a z-index number **smaller** than your menu.  For more information about positioning elements, take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=w3schools%20z-index&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp&ei=8HNTT8fhJor58QOtvqHXBA&usg=AFQjCNGo5mGU8EL1dtgS5oJ1TZIetDBRjA&sig2=USqyTtuZLCcOWeu5PhmUIg).